# C) overflow in file pointer at fprintf()

Tags: c, linked-list, printf

I'm new in programming and trying to build stack with linked list at first.

but in printing the element contained by list, `fprintf()` does not work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//define stack and function
typedef struct element {
    int xindex;
    int yindex;
} element;

typedef struct _node {
    element value;
    struct _node *next;
    struct _node *prev;
} node;

typedef node *nptr;

typedef struct _stack {
    nptr top;
} stack;

void push(stack *sptr, element item);
element pop(stack *sptr);
void free_stack(stack *sptr);
void print_stack(node *now, FILE *fp);

int main() {
    // READ TEXT
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    int stx, sty, fix, fiy, Maze[Maxsize][Maxsize], i, j, k;
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n%d %d", &sty, &stx, &fiy, &fix);

... read rest of txt...

    //build list and keep startpoint
    stack *WaysOut = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    WaysOut->top = NULL;
    element start;
    int nowx = stx;
    int nowy = sty;
    start.xindex = nowx;
    start.yindex = nowy;
    nptr head = (nptr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->value = start;
    head->next = WaysOut->top;
    WaysOut->top = head;

... construct list ... 

    fflush(fp);
    fp = fopen("OUTPUT.txt", "w");
    if (WaysOut == NULL) {
        rewind(fp);
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n", "NO WAY");
    } else {
        print_stack(head, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    free_stack(WaysOut);
    return 0;
}

void print_stack(node *now, FILE *fp) {
    while (now != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", now->value.yindex - 1, now->value.xindex);
        printf("%d %d\n", now->value.yindex - 1, now->value.xindex);
        now = now->prev;
    }
    return;
}
```

when I run this, 'OUTPUT.txt' is built but nothing in text.
I think it is due to the file pointer `fp`, since when I tried `stdout` instead of `fp` it runs well. What is the difference between them caused this?

Thank you.

Comment: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

```
The problem is in this part most likely the now variable is trying to access out of 
memory.

void print_stack(node *now, FILE *fp) {
    while (now != NULL) {
        //fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", now->value.yindex - 1, now->value.xindex);
        //printf("%d %d\n", now->value.yindex - 1, now->value.xindex);
        now = now->prev;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Advice!
The break condition(now != NULL) seems to be the reason of it.
I change it by now==sptr->top and solve it.

Comment: Thanks @S.J JEEE for the upvote glad to help you { :)

Answer (score 0):

```
fflush(fp)
```

before

```
fp = fopen("OUTPUT.txt","w");
```

is an issue. You should be calling `fclose(fp)` instead of `fflush(fp)` if you want to reuse `fp`. Also call `fclose(fp)`before return.

Or you can use different variable

```
FILE *fp1 = fopen("OUTPUT.txt","w");
```

and then call `fclose(fp1)` before return.

Answer (score 0):

The program is incomplete. A likely explanation for the empty **OUTPUT.txt** file is  `head`  might be `NULL` when you output the path.

Instead of testing `WaysOut` which is certainly not null, you should test `WaysOut->top` and pass that to `print_stack`.

Furthermore, you should `fclose(fp)` when you are done reading the input file. `fflush(fp)` is incorrect for a file open for reading and insufficient to release the resources allocated for the stream pointer. Also close the output file before returning from `main()` in all cases, not just the `else` branch of the test.

More generally, always test for errors and report a meaningful error message so the problem can be more easily located and corrected.

Also note that it is confusing and error prone to hide pointers behind typedefs. Better make these pointers explicit.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//define stack and function
typedef struct element {
    int xindex;
    int yindex;
} element;

typedef struct node {
    element value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

typedef struct _stack {
    node *top;
} stack;

void push(stack *sptr, element item);
element pop(stack *sptr);
void free_stack(stack *sptr);
void print_stack(node *now, FILE *fp);

int main() {
    // READ TEXT
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open example.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int stx, sty, fix, fiy, Maze[Maxsize][Maxsize], i, j, k;

    fscanf(fp, "%d %d\n%d %d", &sty, &stx, &fiy, &fix);

    ... read rest of txt...

    fclose(fp);

    //build list and keep startpoint
    stack *WaysOut = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (WaysOut == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate WaysOut\n");
        return 1;
    }
    WaysOut->top = NULL;
    element start;
    int nowx = stx;
    int nowy = sty;
    start.xindex = nowx;
    start.yindex = nowy;
    node *head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate head\n");
        return 1;
    }
    head->value = start;
    head->next = WaysOut->top;
    WaysOut->top = head;

    ... construct list ... 

    fp = fopen("OUTPUT.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open OUTPUT.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (WaysOut->top == NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", "NO WAY");
        printf("%s\n", "NO WAY");
    } else {
        print_stack(WaysOut->top, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    free_stack(WaysOut);
    return 0;
}

void print_stack(node *np, FILE *fp) {
    while (np != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", np->value.yindex - 1, np->value.xindex);
        printf("%d %d\n", np->value.yindex - 1, np->value.xindex);
        np = np->prev;
    }
}
```